# Removing invalid named ranges in GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have defined some named ranges in a sheet that I later delete. Afterwards, the ranges remain in the sidebar "Data->Named ranges...", with the range "#REF". I would like to delete them because I don't want them to accumulate.

They are not listed in `SpreadsheetApp.GetActiveSpreadsheet.getNamedRanges()`.

How can I delete them programatically?

An alternative solution would be how to define a named range that is removed when a sheet is deleted. This happens if you have a named range in a sheet that is duplicated - the named range has a name like "'Sheet1Copy'!RangeName", but it's not possible to define a name like this.

Comment: The command is misspelled. The correct spelling is :`SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getNamedRanges()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `removeNamedRange(name)` to remove a Named Range. It will work even with Named Ranges that has #REF! as range and are not returned by `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getNamedRanges()`.

In order to make easier to maintain your spreadsheets free of Named Ranges with #REF! as range, keep a list of your Named Ranges. You could use an auxiliary spreadsheet for that.

Comment: Thank you. I think, it's not normal behavior of `getNamedRanges()` function. It won't show ranges with "#REF", but they appear in list of named ranges, which is very annoying. Is there an open issue to resolve this?

Comment: @MaxMakhrov: I didn't find yet an specific issue about this.

Comment: Can this be made to work with Named Ranges that are scoped to a Sheet rather than the Spreadsheet?

Comment: @Todd Have you already tried this with sheet scoped named ranges?

Comment: Whenever I've called `.getNamedRanges()` recently on a Sheet or Spreadsheet that contains a bad reference, it throws an error. Only a few weeks ago, I was able to call that function, loop through and test for a specific name, and reset the Range via the `.setRange()` function. Tried the same script today, no go. Seems like Google hates Named Ranges.

Comment: That is very strange. The project I was testing in may have something else going on that is preventing successfully looping through bad referenced ranges. Tested in another Spreadsheet and it was fine.

Comment: @Todd It looks that your spreadsheet has an issue that is beyond the scope of this Q/A. Have you already posted a new question?

Comment: Rubén and @Max Makhrov, It seems that in the current stage, this cannot still be resolved as the native methods of Google Spreadsheet service and Sheets API. So, although I think that this is the complete workaround, as the current workaround, how about this method? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72877125

Answer (score 3):

### UPDATED BELOW

The accepted answer works fine if you are removing a unique Named Range, but not if you have more than one Range sharing the same Name (i.e. Sheet-scoped Named Ranges vs Spreadsheet-scoped Named Ranges).

The first instance of the Named Range will probably be scoped to the entire Spreadsheet, whereas any copies of the Sheet (that contain the original Named Range) will feature Named Ranges that are scoped to the copied Sheet (e.g. `'SheetCopy'!NamedRange` instead of `NamedRange`).

If you want to remove Sheet-scoped Named Ranges whose references are no longer valid, try running the following script from the Script Editor:

```
function removeDeadReferences()
{
  var activeSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  var sheets = activeSS.getSheets();
  
  var sheetNamedRanges, loopRangeA1Notation;
  
  var x, i;
  // minimum sheet count is 1, no need to check for empty array, but why not
  if (sheets.length)
  {
    for (x in sheets)
    {
      sheetNamedRanges = sheets[x].getNamedRanges();
      // check for empty array
      if (sheetNamedRanges.length)
      {
        for (i = 0; i < sheetNamedRanges.length; i++)
        { // get A1 notation of referenced cells for testing purposes
          loopRangeA1Notation = sheetNamedRanges[i].getRange().getA1Notation();
          // check for length to prevent throwing errors during tests
          if (loopRangeA1Notation.length)
          { // check for bad reference
            // note: not sure why the trailing "!" mark is currently omitted
            // ....: so there are added tests to ensure future compatibility
            if (
              loopRangeA1Notation.slice(0,1) === "#"
              || loopRangeA1Notation.slice(-1) === "!"
            || loopRangeA1Notation.indexOf("REF") > -1
            )
            {
              sheetNamedRanges[i].remove();
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Edit / Update

I recently needed to run this script again, and Google must've made changes to the way the `.getRange()` function works. The previous script will not work if the Named Range contains an invalid reference.

Also, after re-reading the initial question, I feel like I was too focused on the Sheet-scoped aspect of the answer.

The OP seemed to be after more of an automated experience, which the Accepted Answer does not provide. In addition to not requiring an externally maintained list of Named Ranges, the following script will remove both Sheet-scoped and Spreadsheet-scoped Named Ranges that contain invalid references.

Here's the updated script, tested to work with the V8 engine:

```
function removeDeadReferences()
{
  var activeSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  var sheets = activeSS.getSheets();
  var sheet;
  var sheetName;
  
  var sheetNamedRanges, sheetNamedRange, sheetNamedRangeName;
  var loopRange, loopRangeA1Notation;
  
  var x, i;
  // minimum sheet count is 1, no need to check for empty array
  for (x in sheets)
  {
    sheet = sheets[x];
    // for logging
    sheetName = sheet.getName();

    sheetNamedRanges = sheet.getNamedRanges();
    // check for empty array
    if (sheetNamedRanges.length)
    {
      for (i = 0; i < sheetNamedRanges.length; i++)
      {
        sheetNamedRange = sheetNamedRanges[i];
        // for logging
        sheetNamedRangeName = sheetNamedRange.getName();

        // v8 engine won't allow you to get range if it is invalid
        try {
          loopRange = sheetNamedRange.getRange();
        }
        catch (error)
        {
          Logger.log(error);

          loopRange = null;
        }
        // get A1 notation of referenced cells for testing purposes
        loopRangeA1Notation = (
          loopRange != null
          ? loopRange.getA1Notation()
          : false
        );
        // check for bad reference
        // added tests to ensure future compatibility
        // but any of these should suffice
        // comment out ones you don't want to test for
        if (
          loopRangeA1Notation == false
          || loopRangeA1Notation.slice(0,1) === "#"
          || loopRangeA1Notation.slice(-1) === "!"
          || loopRangeA1Notation.indexOf("REF") > -1
          )
        {
          Logger.log("The named range, '" + sheetNamedRangeName + "', within the Sheet named, '" + sheetName + "', was removed.");
          sheetNamedRange.remove();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks more like a question than an answer. Anyway, have you already took a look to the failures reports on script.google.com for your script?

Comment: I read on here more than I contribute, so my apologies if I didn't phrase my answer correctly. The OP mentions "ranges" and asks about how to remove "them programatically", and I felt like more could have been provided to address the stated goal. (...) There are no Stackdriver logs for it, and the error given in the Editor was something very unhelpful, "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 90, file "maintenance")". I could be missing something, but that reads like a _no-answer_ to me.

Comment: I think that your post should be split. Keep here your contribution regarding the alternative method, and if you want, post a new question about your issue as it looks that it isn't happening to the OP.

Comment: @Rubén, I've updated the answer to provide more context. The AA doesn't really address the second half of the OP's question, which seemed to ask for something more like a "maintenance routine". OP's sounds as though they want to remove any invalid references, not necessarily those that are known at runtime.

Comment: @Todd, this is exactly the script I'm looking for! However, I get `TypeError: sheet.getName is not a function at removeDeadReferences(removeDeadReferences:18:23)`

Comment: @TC76, that function shouldn't be affected by which version of the JS engine you're using, but it wouldn't hurt to check. The first code sample was written pre-V8 and the second (the one you referenced) was tested with V8. The error you've run into makes me wonder if you may be running the script somewhere other then within the HEAD of a Google Apps Script for a Google Spreadsheet. If the icon in the upper left corner is blue instead of green, try opening the Script editor from the "Tools > Script" menu inside the Google Spreadsheet you are trying to remove the invalid named ranges from.

Comment: @Todd I've tried this but it seems as though Google doesn't return the #REF sheets in the ```.getNamedRanges()``` call anymore.  I'm looking for a solution to remove dead named ranges programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

The function below loops sheets and deletes "bad" named ranges.

You may [see it live here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HwUaZk86BtrPdQ1RYILwTcRwJUUClgqtAPEpMAsX0y8/edit#gid=551282276). Make your own copy and go to menu:

`⚡ Test Automation >  Sheets >  Delete Bad Named Ranges`

[image]

please try

```
function test_deleteBadNamedRanges() {
  var sets = {
    delimiter: '|',
    file: '', // leave blank to use active spreadsheet
    sheet_names: 'nonono|Sheet1|Sheet2', // note put empty string or null to use all sheets
    remove_copies: true, // set true to delete 'copy of sheet'!named_ranges
    success_message: 'Removed "bad" named ranges!'
  }
  var result = deleteBadNamedRanges_(sets);
  console.log(result);
  console.log(sets);
}


function deleteBadNamedRanges_(sets) {

  var book, msg = '';
  try {
    if (!sets.file || set.file === '') {
      book = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    } else {
      book = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sets.file);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    msg = 'Could not get the book for some reason.'
    msg += ' The error is: ' + err; 
    return msg;
  }
  if (!book) {
    msg = 'The book object could not be retrieved.'
    return msg;
  }


  /** function to get sheets by names */
  var sheets = [];
  var errors_log = [];
  var getSheetsByNames_ = function(book, names) {
    var sheets = [], sht, msg;
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
      mag = 'ok';
      try {
        sht = book.getSheetByName(names[i]);
      } catch (err) {
        msg = '❌no sheet ' + names[i] + '. ';
        msg += 'Err: ' + err;
        sht = false;
      }
      if (!sht) {
        msg = '❌not found sheet ' + names[i]
      }
      sheets.push(sht);
      errors_log.push(msg);
    }
    return sheets;
  }

  /** get sheets */
  if (!sets.sheet_names || sets.sheet_names === '') {
    sheets = book.getSheets();
  } else {
    sheets =  getSheetsByNames_(
      book,
      sets.sheet_names.split(sets.delimiter));
  }

  /** delete bad named ranges for each sheet */
  var res = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    sets.sheet = sheets[i];
    if (sets.sheet) {
      res.push(deleteBadNamedRangesSheet_(sets))
    } else {
      res.push(errors_log[i]);
    }
  }
  sets.sheet = '_end_of_loop_';

  var result = sets.success_message + '\\n\\n' +
    res.join('\\n');
  return result;

}


/**
 * 
 * delete bad ranges for 1 sheet
 */
function deleteBadNamedRangesSheet_(sets) {

  var sheet = sets.sheet;
  var sheet_name = sets.sheet.getName();

  // for logs
  if (!sets.removed_ramed_ranges) {
    sets.removed_ramed_ranges = [];
  }
  
  /** function to remove named range
   * and log it to memory
   */
  var count_deleted = 0;
  var add2removed_ = function(namedrange, a1, name) {
    namedrange.remove();
    sets.removed_ramed_ranges.push({
      sheet_name: sheet_name,
      name: name,
      a1: a1
    });
    count_deleted++;
    return 0;
  } 

  /** loop and check named ranges */
  var ranges = sheet.getNamedRanges();
  var a1 = '', nr, name = '', check_copy;
  for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
    nr = ranges[i];
    a1 = nr.getRange().getA1Notation();
    name = nr.getName();
    // remove copy of named range
    if (sets.remove_copies) {
      check_copy = name
        .replace(sheet_name, '')
        .substring(0,3);
      if (check_copy === "''!") {
        add2removed_(nr, a1, name);
      }
    }
    // remove named range
    if (a1 == '#REF!') {
      add2removed_(nr, a1, name);
    }
  }

  return '✔️Sheet ' + sheet_name + ', deleted: ' + count_deleted;

}
```