# Unable to get list or delete namedRange which has #REF using google API python

Tags: google-sheets-api

Unable to list or delete the namedRange using python google sheet API if the namedRange is invalid otherwise the original sheet on top of the namedRange is deleted.

Steps to simulate:

1. Create a new google sheet using python API, dump data into a new tab and add a namedRange say new_range (provide a name for the namedRange).
2. Delete the new tab which was created, now check the namedRange new_range it should be #REF
3. Now list the namedRanges for the above sheet, nothing will be returned but in actual google sheet there will be a namedRange new_range with range as #REF
4. You would not be able to add or update or delete a nameRange with the same name new_range unless it is manually deleted in google sheet.

Please suggest a solution for this.

Comment: It seems that in the current stage, Sheets API cannot retrieve the named ranges with the range of `#REF`. How about reporting this to the Google issue tracker? But, fortunately, when the Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp) of Google Apps Script is used, the named ranges can be retrieved and removed. This is from @Rubén 's answer. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38686822/7108653) If you can use Google Apps Script, this is the answer to your question. If you are required to use Node.js, I think that you can also run the Google Apps Script using Node.js with Apps Script API and Web Apps.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Thanks, we used python API. `, I think that python script can be used for this.